# Sum of geometric sequence starting from $m$-th term

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

I am using this formula when calculating geometric sequence sum, starting from $i = 0$:

$$\sum_{i = 0}^{n} ax^i = a\frac{1 - x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

But what if I was starting from $i = 1$ instead?

Is this formula valid and will always work when $x \neq 1$?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}ax^{i} = a \frac{1-x^{n}}{1-x}$$

What if I was starting at some $i = m \quad \land \quad m < n$?

Comment: It's still true that each term is $x$ times the previous term.  It's just that the first term is $ax^m$ instead of $a$.

Comment: **HINT**: Factor out the first term $ax^m$ from your series. What's left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can factorize $x^m$ out of the sum.

$$x^m+x^{m+1}+\cdots+x^n=x^m(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{n-m})$$

Thus you get $\quad\displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=m}^n x^i=x^m\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-m} x^i=x^m\cdot\dfrac{1-x^{n-m+1}}{1-x}=\dfrac{x^m-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$

Multiplying by the const coefficient $a$, changes nothing of course, I omitted it to ease the understanding.

Comment: What kind of reasonable assumptions do I need to make for this to work for a general purpose? Like, I was thinking something like $m < n$

Comment: Or perhaps something like: assume $m \geq 0 \quad \land \quad n > m$?

Comment: You can have $m=n$ since $x^m-x^{m+1}=x^m(1-x)$ and the $1-x$ will cancel with the one on denominator, you are left with just $x^m$ which is the correct answer for the sum of just one element. Also I see no issue with negative exponents. If $m<0$ you still can factorize $x^m$ out and you are left with $1+x+x^2+\cdots$ the standard sum with positive exponents. The result is unchanged. Thus $m\le n$ is the minimal condition.

Comment: I was also thinking $x \neq 1$, but that one is probably obvious. Maybe there's something else 'obvious'? Feel free to post in my new thread: I could accept your answer there, since your answer is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: for any given $m$, $\sum_{i=m}^nax^i=\sum_{i=0}^nax^i-\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}ax^i$

---

More generally, suppose you have a sequence $p_i$ of numbers, and some "nice formula" $P(n)$, depending only on $n$, for $\sum_{i=0}^np_i=P(n)$.

Then we have a "nice formula" $P(n,m)$ for $\sum_{i=m}^n p_i$, namely, $P(n,m)=P(n)-P(m-1)$.

Comment: This seems very much to be the hard way to approach the problem.